# Create signed android apk from an eclipse importe project to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, signed-apk

I created an Anndroid project in eclipse and have published it in the Play Stoore, but now I imported it into Android Studio to make some changes.

Now that I finished my changes I wanted to publish an update of my project.

For this I go to `Build -> Generate` signed APK and I put the location of my keyStore and the respective passwords, alays and the location where I want to store my APK.

Android Studio create the APK file in the desired location.

The problem is when I try to uplod my project to my Google Plusher account I get this error:

You uploaded an unsigned APK. You must create a signed APK.

What can bee the problem? I have used the same keystore that I used to use beffor.

Comment: You are probably uploading the incorrect artifact, double check it is the signed-apk you are trying to upload.

Comment: AS builds multiple artifacts during

Comment: which apk are you copying exactly? Android studio creates 3 to 4 apks when you build signed apk

Comment: Is your query resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the correct APK. The problem was wen I have to select the signature version.I was usin the V2 (Full APK Signature), then I have tried the V1 (Jar Signature) and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

1)Delete your build.

2)Generate sign Apk.

3)check you are uploading a release apk not debug apk.

Or try this link https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can locate the signed APK at `MyProject/app/app-release.apk`.

You can upload this APK on the Google Play Store and it will work like a charm.